# It is possible to create and add it new element using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one code,and i want to create and add new element after specific element but by id or its name using javascript or jquery.It is possible?

here is code:

```
<section class="content " >
            <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="grid no-border top bottom black">
                        <div class="grid-header ">
                            <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
                            <span class="grid-title">Data Insert Form</span>



                            <div class="pull-right grid-tools">
                                <a data-widget="collapse" title="Collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                <a data-widget="reload" title="Reload"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a>
                                <a data-widget="remove" title="Remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="success_message"></div>
                        <div class="grid-body">
                            <?php $data=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from admin_seo_meta_tag_data"));?>
                            <form  id="Data-insert" >


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Page Title</label>
                                    <span style="color:red;" id="Pagetitle_error"></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PageTitle" name="PageTitle" value="<?php echo $data['PageTitle'];?>" onFocus="clear_Pagetitle()">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="uid" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Meta description</label>
                                    <span style="color:red;" id="Metadescription_error"></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $data['MetaDescription'];?>" id="MetaDescription" name="MetaDescription" onFocus="clear_Metadescription()">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Meta Keywords</label>
                                    <span style="color:red;" id="Metakeyword_error"></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="MetaKeywords" name="MetaKeywords" value="<?php echo $data['MetaKeywords'];?>" onFocus="clear_Metakeyword()">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Location</label>
                                    <span style="color:red;" id="Loc_error"></span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Location" name="Location" value="<?php echo $data['Location'];?>" onFocus="clear_Loc()">
                                </div>


                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" onclick="UpdateSeoData()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                    <button type="text" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </section>
```

Now i am insert data using ajax  getting success,now i want to create new div in which will show success message,i need to create it dynamically because i am creating dynamic inser,update form which do not know about user created div name

thank you all for your help
finally work done

```
$('.content-header').append('<div class="success_msg"></div>');
                                                        $('.success_msg').html("<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert' style='font-size: 15px;'><?php echo $message["success"];?></div>");
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Your question is incomplete, it should contain code sample, what you have done

Comment: Yes it is possible. But can you show us your code? So will be able to assist you more properly

Comment: Yes, you should use: `document.createElement` method, here is a good reference from MDN: [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: ok let me explain fully, ihave one form which get data insert or update using ajax,i am getting ajax success message now i need to display success message using creating new div and display and then disappear but main problem is that i want to show that message at one spacific place or after fix div which i can't do

Comment: i know how to create but how to append it to after specific div which i want?

Comment: @MJ8042 It sounds like you need this: [jQuery.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take a moment to take the tour to understand how to use the platform http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: yup i need it too much

Comment: I've added an answer with code example and a reference for the function you are looking for, hope it helps. Now I ask from you (as @AhmadAlfy already said) to find some time and to learn how this system works. If you do that, it will be easier for you to get help next time & also make your posts more useful for the future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To question:

> I want to create and add new element after specific element but by id or its name using javascript or jquery. It is possible?

The answer is: **Yes it is possible**

There are a lot of completely different ways to do it, but If I understand your explanation in comments, then what you need is to use the method: [jQuery.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

Here is a code example, of how it can be done:

```js
$(function(){
  //Assume yourDiv - is an element that you want to add after element by id="one"
  var yourDiv="<div>Added after #one</div>";
  $(yourDiv).insertAfter("#one");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="one">content of ONE</div>
 <div id="two">content of TWO</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Side note**: jQuery is a Javascript library, so even that I understand what you meant by: "javascript or jquery", but in practical terms it's just Javascript.

**Edit** *Added after OP added code sample*:
After seen your code sample, I couldn't ignore a few things:

**First** - Methods `mysql_query`,`mysql_fetch`, etc shouldn't be used anymore, as stated in PHP [official reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

> ...was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used...

I recommend to use: [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

**Second** - Using `$_GET` directly (or any other data that came from client) is UNSAFE. Take a look at: [Data validation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation)

> ...Data from the client should never be trusted...

I recommend to use: [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) and to check (don't want to sound paranoid but still) every possible bad scenario case.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    function UpdateSeoData(){
         $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  file.php,
                dataType: 'json', // data type of response      
                data: JSON,
                contentType:'application/json',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#abcd').append('SuccesFully Insrted');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                handleErrors('Error: ' , textStatus , errorThrown);
                }


            });

    }     
        })
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="abcd"></div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Bro i have given the execued code which he should use in his ans thats it not to do his entire cod

Comment: @might be obvious to you but not to other people. If you're trying to provide entire *Document preview* code than make sure to use the proper `<!DOCTYPE html>` and include the necessary. Also, first make sure and answer does not already exists here on StackOverflow that already covers that question. Also, explaining shortly what are your changes and improvements would help.

Comment: Now i included what you expected sir..but i am also trying to give answer day by day i will learn from you guys how to answer